# I am not able to select owner while creating case ?Why Case Owner is the case creating person for financial services cloud and why it is not producer?

Tags: case-object, financial-services-cloud, policies

When I am creating a case in Salesforce for financial services, why is the owner the person creating the case? As per my knowledge Case owner should be the producer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its by default the Case creator,  you can define the default owner in /lightning/setup/CaseSettings/home in your org.  You should define your support settings as well there.

Comment: Can I change it to lookup of the producers? I want only to see this field as a producer selection so that the producer will get an email for the case and reply back  to the case and those reply comments from the cases creator and producer can see by each other.

Comment: No, not really. This just sets a default case owner so that case records are not orphaned.  And case owners are by default Salesforce users, not contact records or Account records.

Comment: I have created a digital experience sites and enables a contact as a customer and while login to the portal Policies related to one customer is showing to the other customer too
I have updated the settings given in the some resolution links too but nothing works 
Example customer A is having policy A and customer B is having Policy B but when I am login to the portal with different customer's I can only see one policy Policy A under both of the customers.